# React not rendering correctly layout after redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

I have an app that uses styled-components and material-ui. I have private routes configurated, based on the user role and if the user is not authenticated I should return him to login page. But when that happen the layout do no load.

**App.tsx**

```js
import React from 'react';

import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import { ThemeProvider as StyledThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';

import Routes from './routes';
import { configureStore } from './store/configure-store';
import GlobalStyle from './styles/globalTheme';
import defaultTheme from './styles/theme/default.theme';

const { store, persistor } = configureStore();
const theme = createMuiTheme({});

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <StyledThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
          <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
            <GlobalStyle />
            <Routes />
            <ToastContainer />
          </PersistGate>
        </StyledThemeProvider>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**routes.tsx**

```js
import React, { memo } from 'react';

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import NotFound from '../components/NotFound';
import Dashboard from '../pages/Dashboard';
import Login from '../pages/Login';
import Register from '../pages/Register';
import { ProtectedRoute } from './permissions-route';

function Routes() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <ProtectedRoute
          path="/dashboard"
          component={Dashboard}
          requiredRole={['USER']}
        />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/cadastro" component={Register} />
        <Route exact path="/error" component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default memo(Routes);
```

**permission-route.tsx**

```js
import React from 'react';

import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import { RootState } from '../store/configure-store';

interface Teste {
  path: any;
  component: any;
  render?: any;
  requiredRole: any;
}

export const ProtectedRoute = ({
  path,
  component: Component,
  render,
  requiredRole,
  ...rest
}: Teste) => {
  const userRole = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.user.role);
  return (
    <Route
      path={path}
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        if (requiredRole.includes(userRole)) {
          return Component ? <Component {...props} /> : render(props);
        }

        return <Redirect to="/login" />;
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

What happens after redirect occurs

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the `<Redirect />` component, try `window.location.href = "/login";`

```
return (
  <Route
    path={path}
    {...rest}
    render={(props) => {
      if (requiredRole.includes(userRole)) {
        return Component ? <Component {...props} /> : render(props);
      }

      window.location.href = "/login";
    }}
  />
);
```

This should refresh the page and make it get the proper stylings again

Comment: Using window.location.href it works. But i can't understand why won't work with <Redirect /> or even history.push

Comment: It's because doing `<Redirect />` or `history.push` just renders the other component, and changing `window.history.href` actually refreshes the page and somehow it refreshes the styling for other components as well. The same goes with `<Link>` vs `<a>`. Now this is just kind of a workaround, whatever issue you have with your styling not loading in new components when they mount is either something unique to that component, or something that you need to deal with everywhere (unless you get it fixed). Because that is the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using MUI and Router.

I found that I was importing different versions of MUI: `@mui` and `@material-ui` after **replacing `@material-ui` components and uninstalling it, the issue was resolved.**

Most likely this is an issue with conflicting styling.

I suggest **checking browser DevTools** to see what files/classes are overriding these styles **after redirect**.